# run time error 1004 when I use vba search function

Tags: vba, search

I'm practicing some function

when I run below it returns run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Public Sub se()
        a = 2
        While a < 6
            c = WorksheetFunction.IfError(WorksheetFunction.Search("1", "ella"), 100)
            MsgBox c
            a = a + 1
        Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be usefull http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/51443-help-application-worksheetfunction-search.html

Comment: thanks dee. i tried to add on error resume next, it works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you seem to be trying to achieve, I'd suggest using the `InStr` function instead. `InStr` will search a string and will return the position where it first occurs. If the searched for string does not occur within the string being searched, `0` will be returned.

Here's how it's used:

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

A working example c/o [Tech on the Net](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php):

```
InStr(1, "Tech on the Net", "the")
'Result: 9'

InStr("Tech on the Net", "the")
'Result: 9'

InStr(10, "Tech on the Net", "t")
'Result: 15'

InStr("Tech on the Net", "z")
'Result: 0'
```